# css commas psuedo element selectors and compressors

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I came across a curly problem in some CSS where there were multiple psuedo selectors with grouping (commas). When the page was running in development the classes applied properly across browser, but when minified the whole rule would fail.

Explicitly defining each selector works:

```css
input[type=range].event::-ms-thumb {
  background: var(--event);
}
input[type=range].event::-moz-range-thumb{
  background: var(--event);
}
input[type=range].event::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background: var(--event);
}
```

Refactored to use a grouping selector, also works IF there is a space behind the comma:

```css
input[type=range].event::-ms-thumb ,
input[type=range].event::-moz-range-thumb ,
input[type=range].event::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    background: var(--event);
}
```

when compressed the CSS most tools I've tried all remove the 'unnecessary' white space elements and the rule now fails:

```css
input[type=range].event::-ms-thumb,input[type=range].event::-moz-range-thumb,input[type=range].event::-webkit-slider-thumb{background:var(--event)}
```

Turns out that the comma, which is normally a [grouping selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#grouping), is then 'seen' as part of the first psuedo selector name and thus invalidates the entire rule (found in latest Edge, Chrome, Firefox and Safari).

With a comma behind the rule in compressed form, the rule works again.

```css
input[type=range].event::-ms-thumb ,input[type=range].event::-moz-range-thumb ,input[type=range].event::-webkit-slider-thumb{background:var(--event)}
```

I read up and down the spec https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/ and didn't find mention of this behaviour for psuedo selectors, so I figured I'd have to build an extra step to my deploy script after modification to find commas in minified css and put a space ahead of them and in my very small test case this works. Is there anything within CSS that defines how commas should be used? Are there any compressors that account for commas in psuedo selectors properly? Can anyone think of any reason replacing `,` with  `,` will break something?

Comment: I'm curious, hope that someone will be able to answer this.

Comment: I'm not able to recreate the issue. What does your HTML look like?

Comment: with or without space, all the grouping combination should fail because each selector target a specific browser and each browser will see the whole rule as invalid. Try to create a code where we can see the rules working together

Comment: Check if it's a file encoding issue, or a syntax error elsewhere in the stylesheet. Parsers don't consider the comma part of a pseudo token unless it's within a function token.